# Use cached data inside api routes in nextjs with node-cache

Tags: node.js, caching, next.js

I am looking to set cached data stored in nextjs api routes using node-cache package. I have set some cached data using node-cache inside getServerSideProps() method. I am trying to fetch stored cache inside one of my api route but getting **undefined**. Below is my implementation

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const data = {username:'Philip'}
  let cachedData:any = await Cache.get('cachedObject');
  console.log('cachedObject', cachedData)
  if(!cachedData){
    cachedData = await Cache.set('cachedObject', data, 10000);
  }

  return {
    props:data
  };
};
```

In same application I have one api route like below

```
import Cache from '../cache'
export default async function handler(req: any, res: any) {
    const cachedData = await Cache.get('cachedObject');
    console.log('cachedDataApi', cachedData)
    res.status(400).json({ success: true});
}
```

Below is my cache.js configuration

```
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');

class Cache {
  constructor() {
    this.cache = new NodeCache();
  }

  get(key) {
    return this.cache.get(key);
  }

  set(key, value, ttl) {
    this.cache.set(key, value, ttl);
  }
}

module.exports = new Cache();
```